# Error C1189 MFC

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I already searched for solutions online, but nothing helped me. 
I want to code a simple Chat in C++, everything is fine, but I get this error:

> error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]

I already defined

```
#define _AFXDLL
```

but the error is still occures. Any help is apprecicated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two settings that must agree with each other:

```
(1) Project > Properties > General > Use of MFC
(2) Project > Properties > C/C++ / Code Generation / Runtime Library
```

If (1) is set to `Use MFC in static library`, then (2) must be `Multithreaded (/MT)` or `Multithreaded Debug (/MTd)` (in Release and Debug builds, correspondingly). If (1) is `Use MFC in Shared DLL`, then (2) must be `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)` or `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)`.

When the two don't agree, you get the error you've shown.

Comment: @Jan: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) Adhering to these conventions will make stackoverflow.com more valuable to future visitors.