# C1189: #error : ERROR: Use of C runtime library internal header file

Tags: c++, mfc, crtdbg.h

I am trying to build a code using VS 2008 professional and windows CE 6.0 SDK.

I was getting one error fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory. I have included the following paths in the Tools ->options->VC++ Directories->Include

```
files$(VCInstallDir)ce\include
C:\Program Files\Windows CE Tools\SDKs\Toradex_CE600\include\ARMv4I
C:\Program Files\Windows CE Tools\SDKs\Toradex_CE600\include
$(VCInstallDir)ce\atlmfc\include
$(VSInstallDir)SmartDevices\SDK\SQL Server\Mobile\v3.0

Tools ->options->VC++ Directories->Include files$(VCInstallDir)ce\Library filesC:\Program Files\Windows CE Tools\SDKs\Toradex_CE600\lib\ARMv4I
$(VCInstallDir)ce\atlmfc\lib\ARMv4I
$(VCInstallDir)ce\lib\ARMv4I

Tools ->options->VC++ Directories->Include files$(VCInstallDir)ce\source filesC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include
$(VCInstallDir)ce\atlmfc\src\atl
$(VCInstallDir)ce\atlmfc\src\mfc
$(VCInstallDir)ce\crt\src

Also the solution->properties->Debug source files has the following paths.

c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\crt\src\
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\include\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include
```

This file is used in my startup project. My solution has 10 projects(MFC static library). 9 out of 10 are successfully compiled. Just this project is giving this error. So included the path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\crt\src in that projects additional directories. Now its giving me this error. 
 Can you please help me.

Comment: `C1083` or `C1189`?

Comment: actually i was getting C1083 error. Then i just tried including the path of that crtdbg.h file in my projects additional directory. Now i am left with C1189. I donot know what is correct. How do i link the path of that file to my solution or project.

Comment: [`C1189` is already explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197158/error-c1189-mfc). I'm sure you can find an explanation for `C1083` as well.

Comment: C1189 i have tried what is explained in that link, still im getting the error.